# Can a PyQt program consume a DBus interface that exposes custom C++ types (marhsalled via Qt's MetaType system)? If so, how?

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, dbus

I have a Qt/C++ application that exposes some custom C++ classes via DBus methods [(by registering them as MetaTypes, and using annotations in the xml](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/D-Bus/CustomTypes)), and I want my PyQt program to consume these methods.

The problem I see is that the exposed types are C++ classes, not python, so how can I make python aware of these classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'C++ classes' in D-Bus, it is language-agnostic. All methods, functions, etc. have type signatures expressible in basic D-Bus types (see [the spec](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-protocol-signatures)). Just call those classes, and it should work.

Comment: The point of registering custom classes with Qt's Dbus system is so I can use them in dbus methods and Qt will handle the serialization behind the scenes. I want to achieve the same abstraction in my python client. It doesn't "just work".

Comment: Python's DBus library does handle all the serialization itself. You don't have to declare anything or register anything in advance to consume a C++ DBus interface in python. You do not need any adapter or interface classes as in C++. Read the dbus-python tutorial carefully, and try to call your C++ methods from python like they do in the tutorial.